# i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translation for language en

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

this my code

```
const fallbackLng = ["en"];
const availableLanguages = ["en", "ru"];
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng,
    debug: true,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });
```

I see strange lines in the console

`i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translation for language en {Form: {…}, SignUp: {…}, SignIn: {…}}`

`i18next::backendConnector: loaded namespace translation for language ru {Form: {…}, SignUp: {…}, SignIn: {…}}`

`i18next: languageChanged ru`

`i18next: initialized {debug: true, initImmediate: true, ns: Array(1), defaultNS: Array(1), fallbackLng: Array(1), …}`

all code can be seen here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-fire-k7hhh)

Comment: This is since you have `debug` set to true : )

Comment: @PowellYe Now I get   [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4YMZ/4BmEuP3jK) Why?

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why do I see all this in the console ? How can I remove all this ?

Comment: I don't know exactly - try following the trace.

Answer (score 2):

The i18next library has a debug option that controls whether these debug messages are displayed in the console.

In your current configuration, you have set debug: `true`, that is why you see these messages.

To avoid these messages you can make the debug option `false` hardcoded or make it dynamic based on the `NODE_ENV` environment variable. When `NODE_ENV` is set to `development`, the debug option is `true`; otherwise, it is set to `false`.

your ultimate configuration code should look like this:

```js
const fallbackLng = ["en"];
const availableLanguages = ["en", "ru"];
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    // or
    // debug: false,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  });
```

if you set the debug option false hardcoded you won't see these messages anymore. And if you make its value dynamic when you run your application with `NODE_ENV=development`, you will see the debug messages.

```bash
NODE_ENV=development npm run dev
```

When you run it with `NODE_ENV=production` or without setting `NODE_ENV`, the debug messages won't be shown on the console.

```bash
NODE_ENV=production npm run start

// or
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

Set debug to ***false*** in that object

```
{
    fallbackLng,
    debug: false,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
}
```